# Is the type of propositional equalities actually inductive in the HoTT context?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

The propositional equality type family `_==_` is defined inductively with the only constructor `idp : a == a`. But in the HoTT context it's clear that the type `A == B` may contain elements other than `idp` (after applying the postulated univalence axiom).

1. Is it correct to apply induction principle for type `A == B`? Function definitions using induction on `A == B` seem to be not total.
2. Wouldn't it be more correct to include the univalence axiom as a constructor for type `A == B` rather than have it postulated?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.  See [this post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/02/presentations_and_representati.html) (see the paragraph starting "There’s an important difference" and the next two paragraphs) and also section 5.8 of the HoTT Book.
2. That is indeed an alternative approach to univalence which is currently under development, where instead of generating the identity types inductively we give a type-directed recursive definition of the identity type of each type (with univalence being the clause for the universe).  It's quite tricky to get right.  I wouldn't say that it is *more* correct, but it has advantages (and a few disadvantages).